# How come the if-statement is skipped when I am checking if a string is equal to a number?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers

I am trying to see if the user input is equal to a number, and if it isn't, then show a label saying, "Must be a number" and do not proceed until it is. I never learned about how to check if a string is equal to a number, so I searched it up and added it to my code, but it still doesn't work. Can someone look at it and tell me how I can fix my if-condition? Thank you in advance!

```js
//variable that is used
var user_answer = getNumber("answer_input");

//Confirm your answer with clicking the button
onEvent("attackBttnForEquation", "click", function( ) {
  if (isNaN("user_answer") === false){ //here is where I tried to use it, but it just skips the condition
    showElement("mustBeNum_label");
    setTimeout(function(){
    hideElement("mustBeNum_label");
  }, 1000);
  }
 setScreen("play_screen");
 hideElement("fight_symbol");
 checkAnswer();
 checkLose();
});
```

This is what I tried based on a comment and it still did not work:

```
onEvent("attackBttnForEquation", "click", function( ) {
  if (isNaN(user_answer) === true){ //I forgot to specify that user_answer is a variable, but I even set the condition to equal to true and it did the same thing as before.
    showElement("mustBeNum_label");
    setTimeout(function(){
    hideElement("mustBeNum_label");
  }, 1000);
  }
```

Okay, with the answer I got, the "mustBeNum_label" shows, BUT when the user inputs an actual number, it still shows "mustBeNum_label".

```
//Confirm your answer with clicking the button
onEvent("attackBttnForEquation", "click", function( ) {
  if (Number(user_answer)){
    setScreen("play_screen");
      hideElement("fight_symbol");
      checkAnswer();
      checkLose();
  } else {
    showElement("mustBeNum_label");
    setTimeout(function(){
    hideElement("mustBeNum_label");
  }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: the string *"user_answer"* is Not a Number (NaN), so it is true, not false

Answer (score 1):

Try checking like this:

```
if (Number(user_answer) || user_answer == 0) {
  // input is a number
} else {
  // input is not a number
}
```

You can find out more here: [Number - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Description)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the "mustBeNum_label" shows when it is not a number. But when the user inputs an actual number, it still shows the label.

Comment: Place console.log inside if and else statement, check what is firing, what is not. Alternatively, print the user input before passing it to Number()

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a poor case for `Number()` since it will output `NaN` or a `number`.

Consider when you encounter `0`:  the conditional will run your else block since `0` is falsey.

`Number.isInteger(Number(user_input))` may be a better solution since it will always output a boolean, and if it gets passed `NaN` will output false.

Shorter syntax would be `Number.isInteger(+user_input)`

Comment: I agree that my solution will not work as expected when user inputs 0. And your approach seems to be more suitable here. However, `Number.isInteger()` will not work for non-integer numbers. And nothing wrong with `NaN` output since it's considered to be falsy.
IMHO adding one more check for zero should be enough.

Comment: I passed `+` to the parameter in `Number.isInteger` to force any numbers as strings to numbers just to account for that possibility.